# whats the Missing Number?

Tags: logical-deduction, mathematics, calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

In this grid of numbers, what is the missing number (in place of the question mark)?

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline2&7\\\hline8&9\\\hline\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline0&3\\\hline5&6\\\hline\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline0&11\\\hline10&11\\\hline\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline2&?\\\hline4&3\\\hline\end{array}$$

[(source image in Arabic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAY4l.jpg)

Comment: Does this puzzle have a source?

Comment: Does this puzzle work with the standard arabic numbers?

Comment: doesnt different form of the numbers (arabic or english). i now edited the pictures

Comment: I don't see any difference between the old and the new picture.

Comment: Assuming the numbers map to [this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Arabic_numerals.png) , the 4 matrices are (2,7,8,9), (0,3,5,6), (0, 11, 10, 11), (2, ?, 4, 3)

Comment: thanks bro.he is right. its edited now ( (2,7,8,9), (0,3,5,6), (0, 11, 10, 11), (2, ?, 4, 3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The missing number is

> 1.

because

> You can interpret the two numbers on the top of each grid as a single decimal number, but with the ones digit written first, e.g. "2 7" becomes 72. This top number is then the product of the two numbers below. So 72 = 8*9, 30 = 5*6, 110 = 10*11, and **1**2 = 3*4.

Answer (score 1):

This can be viewed as three equations with 3 unknowns.

$$2A+0B+0C=2$$
$$8A+5B+10C=4$$
$$9A+6B+11C=3$$
$$7A+3B+11C=?$$

$$? = \frac{53}{5}$$

I don't believe this is the intended answer but it is valid.

Alternatively:

$$2A+8B+9C=7$$
$$0A+5B+6C=3$$
$$0A+10B+11C=11$$
$$2A+4B+3C=?$$

$$?=10.6$$

Comment: oh bro, i think it must be from Natural number .